# График работы js

Tags: javascript, график, d3.js

Можете подсказать в какую сторону двигаться или как называется подобный график?[image: График связи модема]

Как реализовать такой график на js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ - найти похожий пример [здесь](https://observablehq.com/@d3/gallery) и поправить его под себя.
Но график несложный в построении - можно самому написать.

Вам понадобятся:

- [axes (ось координат)](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#axes-d3-axis)
- [scaleTime (маштабирование времени на оси](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/v2.2.2/README.md#scaleTime)
- [собственно привязка данных (рекомендую потренироваться на div'ах, чтобы понять, как в d3 работает связывание)](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#joining-data)

```js
const plot = d3.select("#plot")

const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

plot
  .selectAll("div") // выбираем div'ы( на самом деле в DOM их ещё нет)
  .data(items).enter() // связываем данные с выбранными элементами (та самая "магия" d3)
  .append("div") // здесь кол-во div'ов будет равно кол-ву эл-в в массиве items
  .style("width", "100px")
  .style("text-align", "center")
  .style("border", "1px solid")
  .style("background-color", item => item > 3 ? "green" : "blue")
  .text(item => item)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="plot" width="300" height="300"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Ознакомлюсь с материалами, надеюсь все выйдет.